# PyQGIS: Change attribute value doesn't work, results in NULL

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, vector, fields-attributes

I am writing a QGIS plugin, which at one point attempts to change several attribute values on a layer. However, in the end no changes are made. If I punch similar code into the built-in Python Console, it works as expected. 
Code (paraphrased):

```
grid = self.dlg.gridMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
# layer from GUI
prov = grid.dataProvider()
grid.startEditing()

if prov.fieldNameIndex("NewField") == -1:   
    prov.addAttributes( [ QgsField("NewField", QVariant.Int)])
if prov.fieldNameIndex("NewField2") == -1:
    prov.addAttributes( [ QgsField("NewField2", QVariant.Int)])

grid.updateFields()
fldIdx = prov.fieldNameIndex("NewField")
fldIdx2 = prov.fieldNameIndex("NewField2")

for feature in grid.getFeatures():
    ID = feature.id()
    grid.changeAttributeValue(ID, fldIdx, 42)
    grid.changeAttributeValue(ID, fldIdx2, 101)
    grid.updateFeature(feature)

grid.commitChanges()
```

So there are several similar questions on the site that seem like they should answer my question and I believe I've followed advice in the solutions, but to no avail. There is something I am just not seeing!

[How to change the value of an attribute using QgsFeature in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102119/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-attribute-using-qgsfeature-in-pyqgis)
[Got Null values when updating attributes with PyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89754/got-null-values-when-updating-attributes-with-pyqgis)

This does not work either:

```
feature.setAttribute(fldIdx, 42)
```

Comment: I think your problem is `grid.updateFeature(feature) ` try removing that line. I think it's undoing your changes.

Comment: The main problem was I was trying to pass Numpy datatypes and rather than throwing an TypeError, changeAttributeValue just silently failed.

Comment: My problem was not related to datatypes and removing the line updateFeature(feature) solved the issue (QGIS 2.18.21 32 bits)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example code above should work (coincidentally with or without the `grid.updateFeature(feature)`). The problem was in my actual code I was trying to pass Numpy datatypes and rather than throwing an `TypeError`, `changeAttributeValue()` just silently failed.

Always remember to check your variable types when debugging!

Comment: I think I got the same failure (also without error message) in my code [here] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252576/adding-new-values-to-existing-attribute-values-in-pyqgis)? (I'm calculating values as a bumpy array and trying to paste them into the attribute values...) how did you solve your problem?